# How to access/remember unchecked values in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm fiddling around with a Shiny App in R. The app has got

- a select list *Input A* (main groups) with the possible values A,B
  and/or C
- a group of checkboxes *Input b* (subgroups), which are
  dynamically populated by the selection from the *Input A* list: chkb a and chkb
  b for A, c,d for B, and/or e,f for C
- a data frame `df` with the mappings

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

My problem is that *Input b* forgets, which checkboxes were previously unchecked. So - with regards to the screen recording - the value *b* has to be unchecked again with every new selection in the list *Input A*.

**Q: How can I change the below code so that**

1. **Newly added** list items from *Input A* are still **automatically checked** in *Input b*, and
2. previously **unchecked** values from *Input b* are **remembered**; at least as long as the corresponding category in *Input A* isn't unselected

Here's the code:

```
library(shiny)
df <- data.frame(
  a = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 2), 
  b = letters[1:6]
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  column(6, selectInput("selectinput", "Input A", levels(df$a), multiple = T)),
  column(6, checkboxGroupInput("checkinput", "Input b", NULL))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    allPossibleB <- df$b[df$a %in% input$selectinput]
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, 
      "checkinput", "Input b",
      choices = allPossibleB,
      selected = setdiff(allPossibleB, NULL), # <=== previously unchecked instead NULL?
      inline = TRUE
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I tried several things, which I don't think are worth mentioning as I've not too much experience with Shiny and the underlying concepts. Maybe there's a simple way to access not only the checked values of an input widget?

Thanks in advance for any hints & help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `reactiveValues()` to remember the checked values.

I made an edit for a named list to store the info of the checked boxes. This is necessary if you plan to choose `input A` in an alphabetic order,..

```
checked <- as.list(rep(T, length(df$b)))
names(checked) <- df$b
```

Inside the app you will have to use an `isolate()` as the `input$selectinput` updates faster than `input$checkinput` for some reason and this causes a problem in the selection logic. So we only want to update if there is a change in `input$checkinput`. And well yes, I use a for loop to update the list of (un)checked values :).

```
  global <- reactiveValues(checked = checked)

  observe({
    input$checkinput
    isolate({
      if(!is.null(input$checkinput)){
        possible <- as.character(df$b[df$a %in% input$selectinput])
        for(nr in 1:length(possible)){
          global$checked[[possible[nr]]] <- (possible %in% input$checkinput)[nr]
        }
      }
    })
  })
```

The full app would be:

```
library(shiny)

df <- data.frame(
  a = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 2), 
  b = letters[1:6]
)

checked <- as.list(rep(T, length(df$b)))
names(checked) <- df$b


ui <- fluidPage(
  column(6, selectInput("selectinput", "Input A", levels(df$a), multiple = T)),
  column(6, checkboxGroupInput("checkinput", "Input b", NULL))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  global <- reactiveValues(checked = checked)

  observe({
    input$checkinput
    isolate({
      if(!is.null(input$checkinput)){
        possible <- as.character(df$b[df$a %in% input$selectinput])
        for(nr in 1:length(possible)){
          global$checked[[possible[nr]]] <- (possible %in% input$checkinput)[nr]
        }
      }
    })
  })

  observe({
    allPossibleB <- df$b[df$a %in% input$selectinput]
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, 
                             "checkinput", "Input b",
                             choices = allPossibleB,
                             selected = df$b[unlist(global$checked)], # <=== previously unchecked instead NULL?
                             inline = TRUE
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: this is exactly what i was just saying. lol, had to run off to eat with the gf and hadnt posted the code yet.

Comment: took me actually a bit from the idea to the code, not as straightforward as expected,...well i realised as well it only works if you choose `input A` in an alphabetic order,...otherwise it assigns differently. But it shows the general idea good enough,...

Comment: @BigDataScientist Great, that works - thanks. What does the `input$checkinput` between `observe({` and ` isolate({` do? Seems to be critical, but I don't get the meaning there. :-?

Comment: @BigDataScientist Last but not least: choosing a list was a matter of taste, right? The vector lovers might want to change it to sth like `global <- reactiveValues(checked = setNames(rep(F, length(df$b)), df$b))` and `if(!is.null(input$checkinput)){possible <- df$b[df$a %in% input$selectinput];global$checked[possible] <- possible %in% input$checkinput}` inside the first observe.

Comment: @lukeA: See the sentence "So we only want to update if there is a change in `input$checkinput`." That is what i do with the input together with the isolate,...you could also use `observeEvent()` instead. A named vector also works of course,...is actually the better choice as i look at it. The follow up code looks good, but hard to say without testing :)

Answer (score 1):

```
column(6, updateCheckboxGroupInput("checkinput", "Input b", NULL, selected = input$checkinput))
```

or if you have a 'none' option :

```
column(6, updateCheckboxGroupInput("checkinput", "Input b", NULL, selected = if(is.null(input$checkinput)){"none"}else{input$checkinput}))
```

for keeping them grouped with A, B, C you could create reactiveValues that store the choices for each group and use an observer that would change the active group within the input. I'll post code shortly
heres the promised code, my version of what BigData answered

```
library(shiny)
df <- data.frame(
a = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 2), 
b = letters[1:6]
)

ui <- fluidPage(
 column(6, selectInput("selectinput", "Input A", levels(df$a), multiple =  TRUE)),
 column(6, checkboxGroupInput("checkinput", "Input b", NULL))
 )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
checkin <- reactiveValues(A = NULL,B = NULL, C = NULL,puts = NULL)
observeEvent(input$selectinput,{
  if("A" %in% input$selectinput){
    checkin$A <- input$checkinput[which(input$checkinput %in% df$b[which(df$a[df$b] == "A")])]
  }
  if("B" %in% input$selectinput){
    checkin$B <- input$checkinput[which(input$checkinput %in% df$b[which(df$a[df$b] == "B")])]
  }
  if("C" %in% input$selectinput){
    checkin$C <- input$checkinput[which(input$checkinput %in% df$b[which(df$a[df$b] == "C")])]
  }
    checkin$puts <- c(if(!is.null(checkin$A)){checkin$A},if(!is.null(checkin$B)){checkin$B},if(!is.null(checkin$C)){checkin$C})
  })
observe({
 allPossibleB <- df$b[df$a %in% input$selectinput]
 updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, 
                         "checkinput", "Input b",
                         choices = allPossibleB,
                         selected = checkin$puts ,
                         inline = TRUE
 )
 })
 }

 shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks for you input. The behaviour does not change when using `selected = input$checkinput`, or did I make a mistake? I played around with reactiveValues, too. However, no option satisfied both conditions 1. (auto check the new) and 2. (remember the old).

Comment: my apologies, you should have used the selected = input$checkinput in the `updateCheckboxGroupInput`

Comment: It still seems not to do the trick, however storing a sort of lookup table in a reactiveValues object was a good idea. But I guess I never would have gotten it to work without spending hours - it's not tooo intuitive...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Isn't the outcome the same as with just doing `checkin <- reactiveValues(puts = NULL); observeEvent(input$selectinput, checkin$puts <- input$checkinput)`. I had that before (the point of remembering choices), however this does not auto-select new checkboxes, that was the problem. The `checked` dictionary kinda solves this by auto-setting everything on "checked" by default. At least initially.

Comment: changing `reactiveValues(A=c("a","b")...` would also accomplish this. Its six of one half a dozen of the other, as are most things with R. I didnt post the addendum to my answer as a better answer just as the way I would have done it if i had been left to my own devices. The ability to set the values state in groups is the only difference between the two, essentially. You can set one group to off, one group to on, another to one off one on. Using just input$selectinput doesnt accomplish that

Comment: Thanks @Phi - appreciate your help.