# R Shiny - Saving Combined Inputs from Radio Buttons and Checkboxes

Tags: r, shiny

I'm new to shiny (but not R) and am working to build an app where the user chooses specific rows from a table to export into a csv file. Reduced to its essentials, the table has two columns of factors, and one column of responses.

For example,

[image]

Originally, I had the app set to where the user had checkboxes on the sidebar based on the values in the dataFactor2 column that they could use to select which rows to export. (For example, they could select for export the table rows where dataFactor2 == A, G, and J.) However, that got unwieldy for large numbers of dataFactor1 and dataFactor2 levels.

My idea was to add radio buttons for the levels of dataFactor1. Then, if you selected the radio button for dataFactor1 == X, you would get checkboxes for A, B, and C, and the table would only show the rows where dataFactor1 == X. You'd select row A, B, or C, then you'd move on to Y and Z. At the end of the process, you'd still export the rows that corresponded to the selected levels of dataFactor2.

However, when I try to implement things this way, everything resets when I move from one level of dataFactor1 to the next. Any suggestions for how to capture all the checked boxes?

Sample code below for ui.R:

```
#ui.R

library(shiny)

myFactor1<-c("X", "Y", "Z")
myFactor2<-c() #initialize

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Sample"),

  # Sidebar with radio buttons and checkboxes
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(width=2,

      #display radio button list of factor1 values
      radioButtons("factor1", 
                   label = "dataFactor1",
                   choices=myFactor1), #dynamically generate factor list

      #display checkboxes of factor2 values
      checkboxGroupInput("factor2",
                         label="dataFactor2",
                         choices=myFactor2) #dynamically generate list

    ),

    # Show factor2 selections and table
    mainPanel(

      textOutput("text2"),
      tableOutput("table2")


  )

)

))
```

and server.R:

```
#server.R
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  mydata<-data.frame(dataFactor1=c(rep("X", 3), rep("Y", 4), rep("Z", 5)),
                     dataFactor2=c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", 
                                   "I", "J", "K", "L"),
                     dataResponse=rnorm(12))

  observe({
        factor1Choice<-input$factor1

        myFactor2_list<-mydata$dataFactor2[mydata$dataFactor1==factor1Choice]

        updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "factor2",
                                 choices = myFactor2_list)

        mydata2<-mydata[mydata$dataFactor1==factor1Choice,]

        output$table2<-renderTable(mydata2)

        observe({
          factor2Choice<-input$factor2
          output$text2<-renderText(factor2Choice)

        })

  })

})
```

Comment: I had a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44478182/how-to-access-remember-unchecked-values-in-shiny) a few weeks ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any suggestions for how to capture all the checked boxes?

With regards to both answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44478182/how-to-access-remember-unchecked-values-in-shiny), you could do (quick&dirty):

```
myFactor1<-c("X", "Y", "Z")
myFactor2<-c() #initialize

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Sample"),

  # Sidebar with radio buttons and checkboxes
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(width=2,

      #display radio button list of factor1 values
      radioButtons("factor1", 
                   label = "dataFactor1",
                   choices=myFactor1), #dynamically generate factor list

      #display checkboxes of factor2 values
      checkboxGroupInput("factor2",
                         label="dataFactor2",
                         choices=myFactor2) #dynamically generate list

    ),

    # Show factor2 selections and table
    mainPanel(

      textOutput("text2"),
      tableOutput("table2")


  )

)

)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  mydata<-data.frame(dataFactor1=c(rep("X", 3), rep("Y", 4), rep("Z", 5)),
                     dataFactor2=c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", 
                                   "I", "J", "K", "L"),
                     dataResponse=rnorm(12))

  values <- reactiveValues(cb = with(mydata, setNames(rep(FALSE, nlevels(dataFactor2)), levels(dataFactor2))))  

  observeEvent(input$factor2, {
    myFactor2_list<-mydata$dataFactor2[mydata$dataFactor1==input$factor1]
    values$cb[myFactor2_list] <- myFactor2_list %in% input$factor2
  })

  observe({
        factor1Choice<-input$factor1

        myFactor2_list<-mydata$dataFactor2[mydata$dataFactor1==factor1Choice]

        updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "factor2",
                                 choices = myFactor2_list,
                                 selected = levels(mydata$dataFactor2)[values$cb])

        mydata2<-mydata[mydata$dataFactor1==factor1Choice,]

        output$table2<-renderTable(mydata2)

        observe({
          factor2Choice<-input$factor2
          output$text2<-renderText(factor2Choice)

        })

  })

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The general setup is another issue - I found [these shiny sessions](https://www.rstudio.com/resources/webinars/shiny-developer-conference/) quite interesting and helpful.

Comment: Thanks, @lukeA. This looks pretty close to what I'm trying to do! I'm going to play with this a little more over the holiday weekend.

Answer (score 2):

Here a possible solution using a list to store the selections. All the selected checkboxes are recovered using `unlist`.

```R
library(shiny)

myFactor1<-c("X", "Y", "Z")

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Sample"),
  # Sidebar with radio buttons and checkboxes
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(width=2,
      #display radio button list of factor1 values
      radioButtons("factor1", 
                   label = "dataFactor1",
                   choices=myFactor1), #dynamically generate factor list
      #display checkboxes of factor2 values
      checkboxGroupInput("factor2", label="dataFactor2")
    ),
    # Show factor2 selections and table
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("text2"),
      tableOutput("table2"),
      p("All selections:"),
      textOutput("text3")
    )
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  mydata<-data.frame(dataFactor1=c(rep("X", 3), rep("Y", 4), rep("Z", 5)),
                     dataFactor2=c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", 
                                   "I", "J", "K", "L"),
                     dataResponse=rnorm(12))

  # to store selections
  mySelection <- list()

  observeEvent(input$factor1, {
    factor1Choice<-input$factor1
    myFactor2_list<-mydata$dataFactor2[mydata$dataFactor1==factor1Choice]

    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "factor2",
                             choices = myFactor2_list, 
                             # update with stored selections
                             selected = mySelection[[input$factor1]])

    mydata2<-mydata[mydata$dataFactor1==factor1Choice,]

    output$table2<-renderTable(mydata2)

  })

  observeEvent(input$factor2, {
    # backup the selection
    mySelection[[input$factor1]] <<- input$factor2
    output$text2 <- renderText(mySelection[[input$factor1]])    
    # get all selections
    output$text3 <- renderText(unlist(mySelection))    
  })

})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you, @Geovany. This looks close to what I was trying to do, but it seems that it isn't removing factors that have been checked and then unchecked (for example, if the user chooses one column, then decides to go with another one instead).